# Triggering finalizer in the VS2010 debugger

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, task-parallel-library, finalizer

Using the VS2010 debugger for managed code is it possible to trigger the finalizer thread to run?

Use Case:

Using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) may throw exceptions on the finalizer of the `Task` object if the task it 
self has thrown exceptions and those has not been taken care of.

Verifying a bugfix whos cause was an unhandled can be time consuming since you'll need to wait for the finalizer thread to kick in before beeing sure the fix works properly.

I usually do not code using finalizers myself since it causes lots of headache and I have also mailed Microsoft about this. But while it is like this: How can I trigger the finalizer code to run *from the debugger* as opposed from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no special way to do this from the debugger.

You can trigger it in your code:

```
    int i = 0, j = 1;
    new Task(() => Console.WriteLine(j/i)).Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // make sure it has had plenty of time
    //GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    //GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Console.WriteLine("Did I explode yet?");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Now uncomment the two lines to see the exception appear.

Note this should *only* be used for scenarios like tests; you should't really use `GC` in your regular code.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Helped me a lot. Cant accept yet though. I put this code in a button only visible during debugging and works like a charm.